# Replacing String after a comma

Tags: java

Suppose, I have a string like this

```
A. BCD, B. BGF and C.KLMN
```

and the output will be like this

```
A. BCD et al
```

So, I want replace all content with `el al` after the first `,`. How do I do that?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? What do you think you might use to find out where the first comma is, and take the part of the string before that?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is upvoted !!

Answer (score 3):

An extremely simple one-liner:

```
output= input.split(",")[0] + " et al" ;
```

Please don't comment that this code will fail if there is no comma in `input`, because this case is explicitly **excluded** from the question.  I'm sure the OP already knows how to handle it, and we should all focus on what he/she does **not**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too

```
    String str = "A. BCD, B. BGF and C.KLMN";
    if(str.contains(",")){
        int index = str.indexOf(",");// index of first occurrence
        String newStr = str.substring(0, index) + " el al";
        System.out.println(newStr); 
    } else{
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: This logic will fail if comma is not present in String.

Comment: @DarshanMehta see my edited post, your issue will solve

Answer (score 0):

Get the string after the comma
and replace it with the string you want

for example

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*,\\s*(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abcd,fg;ijkl, cas");

if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Or you can use simple String methods:

```
System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",") + 1).trim());
System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(", ") + 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf method from JAVA API.

```
String str = "A. BCD, B. BGF and C.KLMN";
int index = str.indexOf(",");
String remainingString = "";
if(index != -1){
    remainingString = str.substring(index + 1);
}
```

//Here the remainingString is the string part after first comma.

Now replace it using.

```
str.replace(remainingString, "et al");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps:

- Fetch index of comma using String `indexOf()` method.
- Check if it is positive i.e. comma exists or not.
- If comma does not exist then, no need to do any processing.
- If comma exists then, check if it is the first character? If it is the first character then create a new string and return it.
- If it is not the first character then, fetch the substring upto that index and append it with your required string.

Answer (score 0):

Apache StringUtils are incredibly useful for String manipulation. They contain a heap of methods that extend the base JDK and are nearly all null-safe, ie they return sensible answers rather than throwing null pointer exception if a string happens to be null.

To implement your requirement:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
....

String str =  "A. BCD,  B. BGF and C.KLMN"; // or whatever it happens to be


str = StringUtils.contains(str, ",") ? StringUtils.substringBefore(str, ",") + " et al" : str;
```

In the code above, if a comma is present in str, the first operand will suffix 'et al' to the part of the String prior to the comma. Otherwise if no comma is present then str is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)` method of String as:

```
String str =  "A. BCD,  B. BGF and C.KLMN"; 
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst(",.*"," et al"));
```